# AngularJS handle event from directive in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have the following AngularJS directive (at bottom) and if the link **saveClick()** is clicked then the alert window should be shown:

```
<span save-click="alert('hallo ich binssdsd')" data-ng-dropdown-multiselect options="vm.translatedRoles" selected-model="vm.selectedRoles" external-id-prop="label"></span>
```

but nothing happens. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
directiveModule.directive('ngDropdownMultiselect', ['$filter', '$document', '$compile', '$parse', '$rootScope',
function ($filter, $document, $compile, $parse, $rootScope) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            selectedModel: '=',
            options: '=',
            extraSettings: '=',
            events: '=',
            searchFilter: '=?',
            translationTexts: '=',
            groupBy: '@',
            saveClick: '&'
        },
        template: function (element, attrs) {
            var checkboxes = attrs.checkboxes ? true : false;
            var groups = attrs.groupBy ? true : false;

            var template = '<div class="multiselect-parent btn-group dropdown-multiselect">';
            template += '<li><a data-ng-click="saveClick()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>  {{texts.save}}</a>';
            ...
```

Comment: so you want to invoke a `controller` function from `directive`? have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u748hLvn/4/). go through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a link function to the directive definition object for the alert to work.

Below is the sample code:

**directive.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.directive('testAlert',function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<button ng-click="alertClick()">Test</button>',
     link: function (scope) {
        scope.alertClick = function () {
        alert('Welcome!');
     };
   }
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <test-alert></test-alert>
</div>
```

[WorkingExample](http://jsfiddle.net/a77avdLm/)